# Purpose of diode D1 in this circuit

Tags: mosfet, diodes, resonator

These MOSFETs drive an LC resonator circuit. I'm wondering what the purpose of the diode D1 is.

[image: MOSFET LC driver]

Comment: Please edit your question to provide the full circuit diagram. What you've shown isn't really enough to go on.

Comment: Hardly a readable schematic. I need binoculars to read it.

Answer (score 2):

Probably to allow the resonant tank circuit voltage to exceed the supply rails.

Without the diode, the voltage would be limited by the body diodes in the MOSFETs to the supply rail plus two diode drops.

Comment: Thanks for that Spehro